# Folder permissions in Linux

Tags: php, linux, apache, permissions, centos7

I have a website with two folders writable by Apache. Folder-1 is for uploaded media files, and folder-2 is for downloading a compressed file, for updates. Uploading files to folder-1 works fine, but downloading the tar.gz file to folder-2 gives Permission denied. The way I try to transfer the file to folder-2 is with PHP like so:

```
copy($githubRepository, $folder2);
```

After downloading the compressed file, it's supposed to be exctracted and deleted, but the error happends before any of that. Permissions for folder-2 is:

```
drwxrwxr-x+ apache myuser
```

I use the same system on servers maintained by third-parties, and there it works fine. What am I doing wrong? My server runs on CentOS 7, btw.

Comment: Does user apache have read permission on $githubRepository?

Comment: You need double quotes if you want that variable string expansion to work! But better yet, leave them out altogether. Unless of course your directories are _actually_ named `$githubRepository` and `$folder2`.

Comment: Oh, yeah – that was just an example, not the actual code. The quotation marks are a typo. Will edit.

Comment: The github reopository is set to public, so apache should be able to read it, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Hours later, it turns out it was Selinux. I changed it from Enforcing to Permissive, and voila. :)